# Выполнение функции Javascript

Tags: javascript

Вот например у меня есть кнопка, которая открывает блок(убирает с него display и наоборот ставит его). Как сделать так, что при нажатии в другую часть экрана он сам его закрывал, т.е мне не нужно было снова нажимать на эту кнопка, чтобы закрыть блок.

Как пример на сайте [этом](http://myzz.kz/). При поиске песни есть опции и при нажатии на них открывается список, но при нажатии на другую часть экрана, он сам закрывается

Answer (score 1):

```
javascript

function hide_block(){
   //Здесь пишите код который его закроет.
}
function block(){
   //Здесь пишите код который его открывает.
}

HTML

<button onClick="block()" onBlur="hide_block()">Button</button>
```

Хотя этот код будет пытаться закрыть блок в любом случае, когда пользователь будет кликать в окне, просто доработайте его.